# Use upper case on functions and for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

Newbie here.

I have the following code:

```
def names(*args):
    for x in args:
      return sorted(args)

print(names("john", "allison", "tony", "melissa"))
```

I am able to sort the names but I'm not able to use the method .upper() in order to make the name all caps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Why do you need a ```for``` loop in your ```names()``` function when you just want to return ```sorted(args)```?

Answer (score 1):

The args is essentially a tuple. You can either use map to convert to upper, or append to a new list.

First way:

```py
def toUpper(s):
  return s.upper()

def names(*args):
  return sorted(list(map(toUpper, args)))
```

Second way:

```py
def names(*args):
  upperNames = []
  for x in args:
    upperNames.append(x.upper())
  return sorted(upperNames)
```

Both will return lists, just use `tuple(names(...))` to get in tuple form.

Comment: now your explanation doesn't explain the code

Comment: Swapping a lowercase element with an uppercase element is not easy with a tuple, since it's immutable. Makes sense to create a new variable and append to that. I could make `upperNames` a tuple and execute `upperNames += x.upper()` instead.

Comment: no I'm suggesting you edit this ```or convert to a list and use a list comprehension``` to explain the updated code

Comment: Didn't see that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a list comprehension:

```
def names(*args):
    return sorted([i.upper() for i in args])

print(names("john", "allison", "tony", "melissa"))
```

Output:

```
['ALLISON', 'JOHN', 'MELISSA', 'TONY']
```

Edit: without a list comprehension, you can do this:

```
def names(*args):
    upper_lst = []
    for i in args:
        upper_lst.append(i.upper())
    return sorted(upper_lst)
```

Comment: How to do it without list comprehension?

Comment: @HarisBade I've edited it to include without list comprehension

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think of the empty list option